# Entity Framework Core - Many-to-many "shadow query"

Tags: entity-framework-core

Couldn't come up with a good title since I don't know that to name what I'm after :)

My domain is

```
public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set }

    // Many-to-many using CLR join class
    public virtual IList<Youtubes> Youtubes { get; set; }
}

public class Youtubes
{
    public int YoutubeId { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    // Virtual properties omitted
}
```

Only one channel can be marked as `IsPrimary` (this is not possible to enforce at database level with the current design though :).

I've a requirement where I need to sort on a property defined on `Youtube`, namely `Cost` that is nullable int and I'm struggling with how to make this work. In this particular case I'm only concerned with those that are primary (at least the requirement is a such when writing this...).

The sort expression is defined as

```
public Expression<Func<Profile, int>> Exp()
{
    return p => (p.Blog.Cost ?? 0) + (p.Instagram.Cost ?? 0) +
            (p.Youtube.Cost ?? 0); // This was prior to adding many-to-many
}
```

What I want to do is

```
public Expression<Func<Profile, int>> Exp()
{
    return p => (p.Blog.Cost ?? 0) + (p.Instagram.Cost ?? 0) +
            (p.Youtubes.FirstOrDefault(y => i.IsPrimary)?.Cost ?? 0); 
}
```

But that is not allowed inside an expression tree. So how would one go about solving this?

Currently leaning towards creating a `ProfileYouTubePrimary` that will model the zero-to-one relationship between Profile -> Youtubes -> Primary and as such I can enforce that there will at most be one primary channel at database level and at the same the reference that property inside my expression tree.

Input is greately appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not so concise, but you can replace it with `Where` + `Select` + `FirstOrDefault` (no predicate version):

```
public Expression<Func<Profile, int>> Exp()
{
    return p => (p.Blog.Cost ?? 0) + (p.Instagram.Cost ?? 0) +
        p.Youtubes.Where(y => y.IsPrimary).Select(y => y.Cost ?? 0).FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```